# Representation of real numbers under positional systems

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Consider the representation of a real number in the  base $\beta \geq 2$ as the string 
$$
(-1)^\sigma(b_nb_{n-1}\ldots b_0.b_{-1}b_{-2}\ldots)_{\beta} \, ,
$$
where $b_n, b_{n-1}, \ldots$ are integers in the range $[0, \beta-1]$ and $\sigma \in \{0,1\}$ provides the sign of the number. This system for representing real numbers is  called *positional system* with base $\beta$.

It is noted by [Tucker](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=IEN56sqHtR8C&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=exercise+1.1+tucker+numerics&source=bl&ots=egiLpc-ICh&sig=TiJYUINc8akxlJsq5wOJpuluQkU&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=exercise%201.1%20tucker%20numerics&f=false) that the positional system in any base is slightly flawed in the sense that there are real numbers that do not have a unique representation. For example, $(12.254999999\ldots)_{10}$ is equal to $(12.255)_{10}$ and $(100.01101111\ldots)_2$ is equal to $(100.0111)_2$.

So he says that this redundancy can be avoided if we add the requirement that $0\leq b_i\leq \beta-2$ for infinitely many $i$. My question has to do with this requirement because for $\beta = 2$ it implies that $b_i = 0$ for infinitely many $i$. Does it mean that numbers like $(0.01010101010101\ldots)_2$, $(0.1010101010101\ldots)_2$ or $(2.9191919191\ldots)_{10}$ cannot be represented under this scheme?

Comment: $(0.01010101010101…)_2\text{ and }(0.1010101010101…)_2$ obviously have infinitely many $0$s, so how are they not representable?

Comment: As an aside, I don't consider the fact that some numbers have more than one name a flaw. It does mean that the representation is not a bijection, but then this scheme doesn't really solve any problems raised by the representation not being a bijection. It just chooses one representative as being preferred.

Comment: By the way, $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ — the set of infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s — is topologically equivalent to the Cantor set. (See if you can come up with a bijection.) And $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ — the set of infinite sequences of natural numbers — is topologically equivalent to the set of irrationals. (Use continued fractions to construct a bijection.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair obviously they have infinitely many 0s and that's ok but also have infinitely many 1s. That is the thing that apparently violate the condition.

Comment: @dapias - How does infinitely many 1s violate the condition? For base 2, the condition is exactly that the representation has infinitely many 0s. It makes no direct requirement on 1s

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake. Thank you  @PaulSinclair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To say that "$0\leq b_i\leq \beta-2$ for infinitely many $i$" is just a way of saying that there is no $n$ such that $b_i=\beta-1$ for all $i<-n$. That is, the number does not "end" in an infinity sequence of $\beta-1$ only.

$(0.01010101010101\ldots)_2$, $(0.1010101010101\ldots)_2$ or $(2.9191919191\ldots)_{10}$ clearly satisfies the condition of "$0\leq b_i\leq \beta-2$ for infinitely many $i$".

Note that $(0.01010101010101\ldots)_2$, $(0.1010101010101\ldots)_2$ has infinitely many $i$, such that $b_i=0$. And $(2.9191919191\ldots)_{10}$ has infinitely many $i$, such that $0\leq b_i=1\leq 8$.